# How to replace underscore to comma in R

Tags: r

I am learning R programming, here is my data example

```
   trip_id start_location     start_time
     <int> <chr>              <chr>     
 1       1 13.90834_100.50457 05:19:37  
 2       2 13.6753_100.63453  00:05:24  
 3       3 13.66348_100.71868 03:49:54  
 4       4 13.63345_100.71102 04:14:52  
 5       5 13.59653_100.70172 05:01:52  
 6       6 13.57542_100.79453 05:57:11  
 7       7 13.60123_100.71091 06:21:52  
 8   43875 13.94582_100.735   19:28:51  
 9   43876 14.01229_100.66908 20:58:30  
10   43877 13.79245_100.70217 22:09:30
```

also my reproducible example

```
Mon2 <- structure(list(trip_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 43875L,43876L, 43877L), start_location = c("13.90834_100.50457", "13.6753_100.63453","13.66348_100.71868", "13.63345_100.71102", "13.59653_100.70172","13.57542_100.79453", "13.60123_100.71091", "13.94582_100.735","14.01229_100.66908", "13.79245_100.70217"), start_time = c("05:19:37","00:05:24", "03:49:54", "04:14:52", "05:01:52", "05:57:11", "06:21:52","19:28:51", "20:58:30", "22:09:30")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So, I want to change "_" in the start_location's column as a ",". Finally, my result should be like;

```
   trip_id start_location     start_time
     <int> <chr>              <chr>     
 1       1 13.90834, 100.50457 05:19:37  
 2       2 13.6753, 100.63453  00:05:24  
 3       3 13.66348, 100.71868 03:49:54  
 4       4 13.63345, 100.71102 04:14:52  
 5       5 13.59653, 100.70172 05:01:52  
 6       6 13.57542, 100.79453 05:57:11  
 7       7 13.60123, 100.71091 06:21:52  
 8   43875 13.94582, 100.735   19:28:51  
 9   43876 14.01229, 100.66908 20:58:30  
10   43877 13.79245, 100.70217 22:09:30
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Mon2 <-  Mon2 %>% 
    mutate(start_location = str_replace(start_location, "_", ","))
```

-output

```
Mon2
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   trip_id start_location     start_time
     <int> <chr>              <chr>     
 1       1 13.90834,100.50457 05:19:37  
 2       2 13.6753,100.63453  00:05:24  
 3       3 13.66348,100.71868 03:49:54  
 4       4 13.63345,100.71102 04:14:52  
 5       5 13.59653,100.70172 05:01:52  
 6       6 13.57542,100.79453 05:57:11  
 7       7 13.60123,100.71091 06:21:52  
 8   43875 13.94582,100.735   19:28:51  
 9   43876 14.01229,100.66908 20:58:30  
10   43877 13.79245,100.70217 22:09:30
```

---

If we want to do this on multiple columns, use `across`

```
Mon2 <- Mon2 %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('start_'), ~ str_replace_all(., '[_:]', ',')))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   trip_id start_location     start_time
#     <int> <chr>              <chr>     
# 1       1 13.90834,100.50457 05,19,37  
# 2       2 13.6753,100.63453  00,05,24  
# 3       3 13.66348,100.71868 03,49,54  
# 4       4 13.63345,100.71102 04,14,52  
# 5       5 13.59653,100.70172 05,01,52  
# 6       6 13.57542,100.79453 05,57,11  
# 7       7 13.60123,100.71091 06,21,52  
# 8   43875 13.94582,100.735   19,28,51  
# 9   43876 14.01229,100.66908 20,58,30  
#10   43877 13.79245,100.70217 22,09,30
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun it's work. What about if I want to replace my start_time column as well. For example, 05:19:37 to 05,19,37 like this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Mon2$start_time<- gsub( ':',  ',',  Mon2$start_time )

Comment: @Yasumin you can use `across` as in the updated

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any additional library for it, you can use gsub in the base package

```
Mon2$start_location<- gsub('_', ',', Mon2$start_location )
```

Comment: Actually `sub` is enough.

Comment: True as OP only wants to replace the first occurrence, sub would suffice